# pan and scroll in a zoomed in collectionView xcode

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have an app which opens in a UICollectionView.  I can zoom in but I want to be able to pan back and forth and scroll up and down to see the collectionView cells that go outside the view when zoomed in.  How would I do that.  do I have to create a UIViewController and have a scrollView inside of it and then put the CollectionView inside the ScrollView.

As it is I created a UICollectionView and then put a cell inside of it and applied the pinch zoom to the collection view.  but I can't get it to work if I add a scrollView.

Answer (score -1):

I put the collectionView inside a scrollView and got this working.